# How to get 4 types of moving average in single indicator which should be visible in 3 different Time frame?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I got a multi moving average indicator from open source and modified as per my requirement but I want them to be visible in 3 different time frames.

1. Moving Average 10 should be visible only in 5 min time frame
2. Moving Average 20 & 50 should  be visible only in hourly and daily time frame
3. Moving Average 30 should be visible only in weekly time frame

```
study(title="Moving Averages", shorttitle="MAs", overlay=true)
exponential = input(true, title="Exponential MA")

src = close

ma10 = exponential ? ema(src, 10) : sma(src, 10)
ma20 = exponential ? ema(src, 20) : sma(src, 20)
ma50 = exponential ? ema(src, 50) : sma(src, 50)
ma30 = exponential ? ema(src, 30) : sma(src, 30)

plot( ma10, color=orange, style=line, title="MMA10", linewidth=1)
plot( ma20, color=fuchsia, style=line, title="MMA20", linewidth=1)
plot( ma50, color=purple, style=line, title="MMA50", linewidth=1)
plot( ma30, color=black, style=line, title="MMA30", linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeframe.*` built-in variables to check the selected timeframe and then plot accordingly.

For example:

```
is_weekly = timeframe.isweekly
is_five_min = timeframe.isminutes and (timeframe.period == 5)
plot(is_weekly ? ma30 : na, color=black, style=line, title="MMA30", linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but I am getting the moving average when added to chart. I am new to this, can you guide me what command to be used for 5 min time frame, hourly time frame and daily time frame. Your answer will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added an example for the five minute. You should be able to do the rest.